# Dynamically render onclick document.location

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, onclick

I am using the following piece of code:

```
<tr class="itemList" bgcolor="#A5ACB0" onclick="document.location='Details/'>
```

However, I want the document.location to be dynamically rendered so I can do something like this:

```
<tr class="itemList" bgcolor="#A5ACB0" onclick="document.location='Details/' + item.ID">
```

For those asking, item is what I am currently looking at in a for loop and the ID is just the ID of that item. I am using ASP.NET-MVC so this comes from the model of that item.

Comment: what is item.ID ? I think you need `item.id` (case-sensitive)

Comment: you want to redirect to that location on tr click ?

Comment: It needs to be item.ID that is what it is called in my model and yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Does the `Details` action take a parameter of `int id` ?

Comment: I think onclick="document.location='Details/' + @item.ID"

Comment: Yes, the details page requires an ID otherwise it gets a bad request. For example: Details/2 will take you to the details page where the 'thing' in question has an ID of 2.

Comment: onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details",new {id=item.ID})'"

Comment: use function call instead, generally avoid javascript statements inside onclick or in html. and please specify what is item?

Comment: Thanks Musthaan and Frebin, both solutions work. @ThatsME what do you mean use function call? The item is irrelevant, its just what I'm currently 'looking at' in a for loop.

Comment: @jurfer by 'function call' I mean create function inside script tag and then call it,  instead try to use event listener, by doing this JavaScript and HTML code is maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.location` is [read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location), although assigning a string to it should work. You can also use `location.href`.

`<tr class="itemList" bgcolor="#A5ACB0" onclick="location.href='Details/' + item.ID">`

In your code above, `item.ID` is referring to a javascript variable available in the global scope. If you intend to use a value from your MVC model, you need to put an @ symbol in front of it, assuming it's an int.

`<tr class="itemList" bgcolor="#A5ACB0" onclick="location.href='Details/' + @item.ID">`

If it's a string, you need to wrap it in quotes for it to be parsed as a javascript literal string.

`<tr class="itemList" bgcolor="#A5ACB0" onclick="location.href='Details/' + '@item.ID'">`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by read only? I tried both document.location and location.href and both appear to do the same thing? Stupid me, don't know how I managed to forget about using the @ symbol when I've been using it for weeks haha. Also, do you know how I can get the URL to display when you hover over a link like in most other places?

Comment: Sorry, just edited my question, either should work. When you say they 'do the same thing', what do they do? To get the URL to display on hover, you could use a javascript tooltip library, although details for how to do this are out of the scope of your question. Try to implement something and ask another question if you get stuck.

Comment: By the same thing I meant they both work and take me to the right place. I will stick with location.href as that seems to be the 'better' option. Thanks for your help, I'll give it a google now and see what I can find!

Comment: The term read-only is technically correct but confusing. If you try to assign another location, _the browser_ will replace the current document (web page) with a document loaded from the specified location. The changed value of location then is actually a side-effect of the browser's behavior. Semantics. Pffft.